# Poco C++ Net Post Request is handled twice

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I have a strange issue when sending a Post Request to the Poco HTTP Server.
This is my example Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Util/ServerApplication.h>
#include <Poco/Runnable.h>
#include <Poco/Random.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandlerFactory.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h>
#include <Poco/Environment.h>
#include <Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPServer.h>



class ErrorEndpoint : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler {
public:
  

  ErrorEndpoint() {}
  void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response) {
    response.setStatus(status_);

    std::string answer{ R"({"error":"failed"})" };

    response.setContentLength(answer.length());
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    auto& istream = response.send();
    istream << answer;
  }
private:
  std::string errorMessage_{};
  Poco::Net::HTTPResponse::HTTPStatus status_{};
};


class MyRequestHandlerFactory: public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory {
public:
  MyRequestHandlerFactory() {}

  Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler*
  createRequestHandler(const Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request) override {
    
    std::cout << request.getURI() << '\n';

    return new ErrorEndpoint;
  }
};


class MetricsSampleApp : public Poco::Util::ServerApplication {

protected:
  void initialize(Poco::Util::Application& app) override {
    loadConfiguration();
    Poco::Util::ServerApplication::initialize(app);
  }

  int main(const std::vector<std::string>& args) override {

    std::string ver = Poco::format("%d.%d.%d",  static_cast<int>(Poco::Environment::libraryVersion() >> 24),
      static_cast<int>((Poco::Environment::libraryVersion() >> 16) & 0xFF),
      static_cast<int>((Poco::Environment::libraryVersion() >> 8) & 0xFF));

    std::cout << ver << '\n';

    Poco::UInt16 port = 8080;
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket svs(port);
    Poco::Net::HTTPServer srv(new MyRequestHandlerFactory(), svs, new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams());

    srv.start();

    waitForTerminationRequest();

    srv.stop();

    return EXIT_OK;
  }

};

POCO_SERVER_MAIN(MetricsSampleApp)
```

If i'm now running the following command:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:8080/dummy" -H @{"Content-Type" = "application/json"} -Method Post -Body '{"format": "error","node id": "1"}'
```

i get the following output:

```
1.12.3
/dummy
"error","node
```

The first line is the Poco Version which is printed after the start of the example Program.
The second is the URI to which i send the POST Request.
The third is printed together with the second and contains parts of the POST Body.

I'm using Poco in Version 1.12.3 on Windows.
Changing `Invoke-RestMethod` with `curl` leads to the excat same error.